# How to set a frame rate for animation?

Tags: android, animation, refresh

I use animation to rotate an image and i have notice that on higher refresh rate phones (120Hz) the animation is faster.But the animation speeds up only on loading or when i touch a random layout. On phones that use adaptive refresh rate when i touch a layout the phone switches from 60hz to 90 or 120 and animation if speeded up. Has anyone notice this? Can i set a frame rate for that animation? this is my code:

```
Animation  rotationAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.onoffbuttonrotation);
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter = "true"
    android:fillEnabled = "true"
    android:duration="60000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="36000" />
```